# How can I tranlslate post date in italian?

Tags: filters, translation, date

I'm using this filter to display post date in my single and archive pages, because working on a windows azure php app I can't show post date before 1901.

This filter is working but It displays post date in english

```
add_filter( 'get_the_date', function($the_date, $d, $post){
  $date = new DateTime( $post->post_date );
 echo $date->format('j F, Y'); // change formatting as needed 
}, 10, 3 );
```

I need to display the post date in italian. How can I do that?

Thanks guys

ok I solved with

```
echo date_i18n("d F Y (H:i)",$date) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

for example use:
_e('the things to print')

or if woocommerce is being used its possible to use this way:
_e('the things to print', 'woocommerce')

```
add_filter( 'get_the_date', function($the_date, $d, $post){
  $date = new DateTime( $post->post_date );
  echo _e($date->format('j F, Y')); // change formatting as needed 
}, 10, 3 );
```

for more information about [_e()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/_e/)

the text is translated for the wordpress language choosen by the administrator  in  Dashboard > settings > general

Comment: Hi Tiago, thanks for your answer but it doesn't works. In Dashboard > settings > general I set Italian, but it shows always j F, Y in english

Comment: ok solved with echo date_i18n("d F Y (H:i)",$date) ;